# When should one go for webscraping tools? What is the advantage of having web scraping tool?

Tags: web-scraping

I am trying to learn about web scraping tools.

So if anyone help me on getting it started some tutorial links may help.

1. When should one go for web scraping
2. What are the benefits over rss feed?
3. Best tools available in market for web scraping

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the essentials short: "That depends on what you're trying to achieve."

If you have an RSS-feed available with all the information that you need, you don't need to scrape a web page.

If you're trying to extract data from a website that does not provide an API to access the data directly, you can use scraping to extract the information that you want from the page in a structured way. You can save the data into a database and work from there.

For example: In the early Web 2.0 times, there were sites which scraped all other "flight"-pages to extract the cheapest flight for a given source and destination.

Comment: Hi do you have any tutorial links to get things started i found few but i am not sure they were right apify is one i found. Is it something legally correct there won't be any copy rights issue?

Comment: Apify is a nice way to start. You can later scrape web pages with any kind of language, which includes bash scripting, C#, Java, ...

Comment: Errrmmm.... You're voting up by clicking on the Up-Arrow on the left-hand side of the answer. Not by commenting "+1". :)

Comment: votes less than 15 cannot give up! I marked it as useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try web scraping if you need to extract data from websites that don't have an API available, or not a public one, anyway. Also, when you need to harvest data from a large number of sources that you'd be rate limited before you made any serious progress with, even if you had API access.

RSS feeds can be a useful, but they're limited to a tiny subset of curated data the website provides. Like a snapshot of the 10 latest articles on a publication, maybe. Web scraping won't have that limitation. In fact, as long as you identified how the website formatted the data you want into a UI, you could extract anything you wanted at all -- text, images, and even data from tables and lists.

As you can tell, this would be useful for market research, sentiment analysis, price monitoring, and many more cases.

There are several web scraping tools available in the market, some of the popular ones are:

Here are some tutorial links to get you started:

[Web Scraping with Python and BeautifulSoup](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/web-scraping-python-beautifulsoup)

[Web Scraping with Python](https://get.brightdata.com/gm-scraping-with-python)

As for some web scraping tools, you could try these:

[BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/): a Python library for parsing HTML and XML documents

[Scrapy](https://pypi.org/project/Scrapy3/): a Python web crawling framework for building large-scale web scraping projects

[Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer): a Node.js library for controlling headless Chrome or Chromium browsers

[Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/): a suite of tools for automating web browsers

[Bright Data](https://get.brightdata.com/bd7914): an enterprise-grade low-code scraper for uninterrupted scraping at scale, able to get around most website blocks